# Accessing a serialized object contained in non-serialized class in c#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a program code like this

```
namespace Ask{
    public class TestSerialize
    { 
        [Serializable]
        public struct position
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
    };


    public class SubTest:Panel
    {
        public TestSerialize.position pos;
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            SubTest t=new SubTest();
            Console.WriteLine(t.pos.x);
        }
    }
}
```

now accessing pos.x in class test shows warning

Warning     Accessing a member on 'Ask.SubTest.pos' may cause a runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference class

I am weak with serialization concepts so
please suggest how to mitigate this warning ? Is there a workaround or i need to redesign ? 
I dont want to catch an exception here.Anyway to avoid it ?

Comment: are you sure this has something to do with serialization? all i can say is you can not access `t.pos.x` without declaring `x` as public.

Comment: @MuctadirDinar you are right. I have tested and by making them public it work fine. I also included code as an answer.

Comment: i already answered. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a member on Form may cause a runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178576/accessing-a-member-on-form-may-cause-a-runtime-exception-because-it-is-a-field-o)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change x and y of struct to public.

```
[Serializable]
public struct position
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with struct members make them public. See my below program complete copy of your code. Only struct members are public and it compile fine without any warning.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SubTest t = new SubTest();
        Console.WriteLine(t.pos.x);
    }
}

public class TestSerialize
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct position
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }
};


public class SubTest
{
    public TestSerialize.position pos;
}
```

Comment: sorry for inconvinience... please check the edited question .  i am sure the warning is related to serialization and related stuff